# read in json files in Spark df with nested json data PySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to read in multiple JSON files into spark df. JSON data looks like this:

```
{"f0_":{"id":"138307057680","ActionName":"Complete","Time":"2020-04-23-12:40:04"}}
{"f0_":{"id":"138313115245","ActionName":"Midpoint","Time":"2020-06-16-20:41:16"}}
```

I need to get rid of the first key that holds all columns in it.
I tried:

```
jsonFiles = spark.read.json("Resources") # path to all json files
jsonFile.printSchema()
```

The output is:

```
root
 |-- f0_: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ActionName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Time: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Have you tried to `select('f0_.*')`?

Comment: I have not. What is the syntax for select(f0_.*)?

Comment: All dataframes have a select function, as show here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: More on that : https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/transform-complex-data-types-python.html

Comment: Can you please help up vote and approve , if the solution helped you. Thans in advance

Answer (score 2):

This can be a working solution for you ----

**# Create the dataframe here**

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([(str({"f0_":{"id":"138307057680","ActionName":"Complete","Time":"2020-04-23-12:40:04"}})), (str({"f0_":{"id":"138313115245","ActionName":"Midpoint","Time":"2020-06-16-20:41:16"}}))],T.StringType())

df_new = df_new.withColumn('col', F.from_json("value",T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df_new = df_new.select(F.explode("col").alias("x", "y"))


df_new = df_new.withColumn('y', F.from_json("y",T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))

df_new = df_new.withColumn("id", df_new.y.getItem("id")).withColumn("ActionName", df_new.y.getItem("ActionName")).withColumn("Time", df_new.y.getItem("Time"))
df_new.show(truncate=False)
```

**Output here**

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|x  |y                                                                        |id          |ActionName|Time               |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|f0_|[id -> 138307057680, ActionName -> Complete, Time -> 2020-04-23-12:40:04]|138307057680|Complete  |2020-04-23-12:40:04|
|f0_|[id -> 138313115245, ActionName -> Midpoint, Time -> 2020-06-16-20:41:16]|138313115245|Midpoint  |2020-06-16-20:41:16|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
```